# Store Jscript values in Excel

Tags: excel, jscript

I'm trying to transfer the values stored in a JScript matrix to Excel. The problem is how I should initialize the current Excel Workbook that is opened.

For previous works, in python the code is:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel")
import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel as Excel
from System.Runtime.InteropServices import Marshal 
ex = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
ex.Visible = True
wb = ex.ActiveWorkbook
ws_data = wb.Worksheets('name')
```

So my intention is "translate" this code into Jscript to set the values of my matrix in Excel

Answer (score 0):

There is no "global" conversion of this code into JavaScript. Only Internet Explorer supports something called "Active X objects". In other browsers direct communication between JavaScript and Excel is not possible (at least not "out of the box").

In Internet Explorer you can use the following code:

```
var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
```

See more i.e. here [ActiveXObject Object (JavaScript)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/activexobject-object-javascript)